# Joint distribution function of $f(x,y) = e^{-y}$

Tags: integration

Find the joint distribution function of $f(x,y) = e^{-y}, 0 \leq x < y < \infty$.

For $y \geq x$:

$$\int^x_0\int^y_{u} e^{-v}dvdu$$
$$=\int^x_0[  -e^{-v}]^y_udu$$
$$=\int^x_0 e^{-u} -e^{-y}du$$
$$=[ e^{-u} -e^{-y}]^x_0$$
$$=1-e^{-x}-e^{-y}x$$

This is the correct answer.

For $x \geq y$:

$$\int^y_0\int^x_{u} e^{-v}dvdu$$

By proceeding in the same way I get

$$\int^y_0\int^x_{u} e^{-v}dvdu=1-e^{-y}-e^{-x}y$$
This is incorrect. I think that my set up of the integration is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ x>y$ we should have  $\int_0^{y}\int_u^{y} f(u,v)dvdu=1-e^{-y}-ye^{-y}$.